# How to avoid duplicate data in select box when retrieving data from same table

Tags: php, jquery, html

Here is my mysql query with purpose of retrieving BRAND, PATTERNS, AR, and WIDTH from tblInventory where my SZ is match with my input SZ.

```
CREATE TABLE `tblInventory` (


  `BRAND` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PATTERNS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SZ` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AR` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WIDTH` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `tblInventory` (`BRAND`, `PATTERNS`, `AR`, `WIDTH`) VALUES
('OHTSU FALKEN', 'FKU', 70, 165),
('OHTSU FALKEN', 'ZE912', 60, 165),
('OHTSU FALKEN INDO', 'SN828', 70, 155),
('OHTSU FALKEN', 'SN816', 70, 145),
('OHTSU FALKEN', 'SN807', 80, 145),
('OHTSU FALKEN', 'SN807', 80, 155);


SELECT DISTINCT BRAND, PATTERNS, AR, WIDTH FROM tblInventory WHERE SZ='$b_size' ORDER BY SZ ASC
```

JSON method used to storing data into array

```
$result = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $tyre_query);

    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tyreArray[$i] = array(
            "BRAND" =>$row['BRAND'],
            "PATTERNS" =>$row['PATTERNS'],
            "AR" =>$row['AR'],
            "WIDTH" =>$row['WIDTH'],
        );
        ++$i;
    }

    echo json_encode($tyreArray);
```

Then array will pass back to jQuery and append each record to my select box.

```
function(data)
        {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    BRAND = json[i]["BRAND"]
                    MODEL = json[i]["PATTERNS"]
                    AR = json[i]["AR"]
                    WIDTH = json[i]["WIDTH"]
                    //alert(MODEL)
                     $('#cmbTBrand').append($('<option/>', { 
                        value: BRAND,
                        text : BRAND 
                    }));

                    $('#cmbTModel').append($('<option/>', { 
                        value: MODEL,
                        text : MODEL 
                    }));

                    $('#cmbTWidth').append($('<option/>', { 
                        value: WIDTH,
                        text : WIDTH 
                    }));

                    $('#cmbTProfile').append($('<option/>', { 
                        value: AR,
                        text : AR 
                    }));
                }
            })
            count = 1;
```

When I append each of the FIELD into my select box duplicate data will display.

How to avoid the data duplicate in select box?

Answer (score 0):

You can run separate queries for each SELECT box, and add a `GROUP BY` clause to your `SELECT` query to prevent duplicate data.

```
SELECT BRAND
FROM tblInventory 
WHERE SZ='$b_size' 
GROUP BY BRAND
```

---

```
SELECT PATTERNS
FROM tblInventory 
WHERE SZ='$b_size' 
GROUP BY PATTERNS
```

And so on.

### Solution in Javascript

Instead of modifying your queries, you could achieve this all in JavaScript by first building up a set of arrays (objects actually) to represent the unique options of each select box and then another loop to output each select box.

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
var brands = {}, models = {};

for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    BRAND = json[i]["BRAND"]
    MODEL = json[i]["PATTERNS"]
    brands[BRAND] = BRAND;
    models[MODEL] = MODEL;
}

// now you have a list of unique brands and models
```

Comment: actually, you would have to run 4 queries to get all the possible unique values of each column. `SELECT BRAND FROM tblInventory GROUP BY BRAND;`

Comment: are you mean that I should split them all rather than having one query to retrieve the data?

Comment: Yes, that is one way to go. I updated my answer to better explain it and provide a solution in javascript without changing your query (but you need to run more loops in JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and I still not understand the flow after I seperate all of the field into unique select query. As the example query you listed and how to insert those two query into the $result variable ?
LIKE :
$result = mysqli_query ($mydatabase, $t_brand_select, $t_patterns_select); ?